# Is there any software which give me the definition of many English words in English at the same time?

Tags: language, dictionary

I have a list of English words which I'd like to get their meaning in English, as well. Do you know a website/software which tells the meaning of whole words just in one effort? Currently, in all of websites/dictionaries I know, I have to write words one by one and get the meaning of them one by one! It is really tiring to do that for about 600 words. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! While the title of your question asks for a software, the body itself just refers to websites. Please note that we don't do website recommendations here (there's a new SE site in proposal for that on Area51), which would make that off-topic. To me (just my personal opinion) this looks like a candidate for our OpenData sister site (check with their `/help/on-topic` first to make sure), if you'd ask for that data-set (dictionary) to download parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux or a virtual machine with Linux install dict. It is a command line dictionary.

If you want to set up a VM for that purpose I can say that I don't know Ubuntu, but I know for sure that dict is in the Debian repo.

After dict installation you can write a script to parse a text file, pass each word to the dict command and output the result on another text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try My Word List app for Android. You can import an entire list of words, then you can export the words and definitions, along with other data as well:

Free version:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Disclaimer: I am the developer.